# Confusion about unicode-math symbols w.r.t. math/text mode and format

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, unicode, unicode-math

Many math symbols defined by `unicode-math` either "work" in text mode or at least don't produce errors. For example, taking a representative sample from `unicode-math-table.tex`, the following code compiles with lualatex

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math,array,shortvrb}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\MakeShortVerb{\|}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r | M | c | l}
Command & \text{Math mode} & Text mode & Symbol class \\
\hline
|\twolowline| & \twolowline & \twolowline & |\mathord| \\
|\dagger| & \dagger & \dagger & |\mathbin| \\
|\ddagger| & \ddagger & \ddagger & |\mathbin| \\
|\smblkcircle| & \smblkcircle & \smblkcircle & |\mathbin| \\
|\enleadertwodots| & \enleadertwodots & \enleadertwodots & |\mathord| \\
|\unicodeellipsis| & \unicodeellipsis & \unicodeellipsis & |\mathord| \\
|\hyphenbullet| & \hyphenbullet & \hyphenbullet & |\mathord| \\
|\fracslash| & \fracslash & \fracslash & |\mathbin| \\
|\Question| & \Question & \Question & |\mathord| \\
|\closure| & \closure & \closure & |\mathrel| \\
|\qprime| & \qprime & \qprime & |\mathord| \\
|\euro| & \euro & \euro & |\mathord| \\
|\enclosecircle| & \enclosecircle & \enclosecircle & |\mathord| \\
|\enclosesquare| & \enclosesquare & \enclosesquare & |\mathord| \\
|\BbbZ| & \BbbZ & \BbbZ & |\mathalpha| \\
|\mho| & \mho & \mho & |\mathord| \\
|\mfrakZ| & \mfrakZ & \mfrakZ & |\mathalpha| \\
|\turnediota| & \turnediota & \turnediota & |\mathalpha| \\
|\Angstrom| & \Angstrom & \Angstrom & |\mathalpha| \\
|\mscrB| & \mscrB & \mscrB & |\mathalpha| \\
|\mfrakC| & \mfrakC & \mfrakC & |\mathalpha| \\
|\mscre| & \mscre & \mscre & |\mathalpha| \\
|\leftarrow| & \leftarrow & \leftarrow & |\mathrel| \\
|\uparrow| & \uparrow & \uparrow & |\mathrel| \\
|\rightarrow| & \rightarrow & \rightarrow & |\mathrel| \\
|\downarrow| & \downarrow & \downarrow & |\mathrel| \\
|\leftrightarrow| & \leftrightarrow & \leftrightarrow & |\mathrel| \\
|\updownarrow| & \updownarrow & \updownarrow & |\mathrel| \\
|\nwarrow| & \nwarrow & \nwarrow & |\mathrel| \\
|\nearrow| & \nearrow & \nearrow & |\mathrel| \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With lualatex at least, every symbol defined with `\UnicodeMathSymbol` except those in the classes `\mathopen`, `\mathclose`, `\mathaccent(wide)`, `\mathaccentoverlay`, `\mathbotaccent(wide)`, `\mathover`, `\mathunder` will compile in text mode without error. Whether or not a symbol is produced depends on the font, and as can be seen above, the symbol in text mode is often slightly different (expected, as they're coming from different Unicode blocks (I think)).

However, if you try to compile with xelatex, you'll get an error `! Missing $ inserted.` for `\qprime`. It compiles if you remove that line, but in general fewer symbols work in text mode with xelatex.

Last observation: Without unicode-math, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\dagger
\end{document}
```

compiles without error under lualatex, but produces no symbol. With xelatex, it throws an error. Add `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and it compiles and produces a symbol with both formats.

My questions are:

1. Why does lualatex not produce errors when math symbols are used outside of math mode? More generally, why the different behavior between lualatex and xelatex here?
2. Is the choice to make symbols work in text mode intentional on the part of `unicode-math`?

A guess is that `\UnicodeMathSymbol` tells `\dagger` to expand to the literal Unicode character `†` which is then interpreted by lualatex or xelatex in the proper context (math/text). As long as there's no extra code (like for `\mathaccent`) that requires math mode, then the "Math" part of `\UnicodeMathSymbol` is really not important. But this is only a guess, and does not explain why `\qprime` produces an error outside math mode for xelatex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\show\dagger\dagger
\end{document}
```

shows that `\dagger` isn't a macro it is defined as in classic tex via `\mathchardef`. In classic TeX and XeTeX using a `\mathchar` token is an error
but a documented change in luatex is that a `\mathchar` in text is not an error,
the mathclass is ignored and it acts like `\char` selecting a character from the current font.

Adding `unicode-math` you will see, as you guessed, the command is a simple `\def` macro to a character. So like `+` works in text and in math is controlled by the `\mathcode` of the character

```
 \dagger=the character †
```

`\qprime` is not a macro but defined va `\Umathchar`

```
\qprime=\Umathchar"0"00"002057.
```

This acts like `\mathchar` and is an error in text in xetex but luatex ignores the first two components and acts like `\char"002057`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\show\alpha\alpha
\show\dagger\dagger
\show\qprime\qprime
\end{document}
```